# How to handle the auth0 (Authentication Required) popup window in protractor

Tags: node.js, jasmine, protractor, auth0

Im facing an issue to handle the auth0 pop window. Any leads on how do I handle the same.

NOTE : 
1. Protractor is what I'm using.
2. Framework : Jasmine (Nodejs).

Attached is the screenshot for the reference.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgYCe.png)

Thanks,
Zaid

Comment: Please provide more information on your problem.  The relevant HTML, any solutions you have attempted, any issues/errors from your attempted solutions etc.

Comment: The issue is:1. First an auth0 login popup window is displayed (which is a web based pop up), for which i'm able to sale through.
2. Once i click on login button in step1, I get the browser authentication prompt asking for credentials). which I'm unable to handle with protractor.
Solutions attempted:1. Tried using autoIt but could not execute the exe file from jasmine/ protractor.2. I manually tried the approach of https://username:password/url.com which I could successfully do. But then same when i try through protractor the focus remains in the browser authentication prompt. No luck

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured out the solution.

I have a javascript that generates the auth0 token. Once the token is generated I use that token and set that to browser cookies along with user credential. This way when I hit the application url which I want to test, the auth0 browser specific authentication prompt isn't displayed.

Below is the code for the same:
 var request = require('request');

```
this.performAuthoLogin = function() {
    var defer = protractor.promise.defer();
    var credentials = {
        "client_id": clientId,
        "username": userName,
        "password": password,
        "id_token": "",
        "connection": connectionName,
        "grant_type": "password",
        "scope": "openid",
        "device": "api"
    }
    request({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        json: true,
        body: credentials,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
             defer.reject(error);
        } else {
            authTokenId = body.id_token;
            console.log(authTokenId);
            var profile = {
              username: userNameToLogin
              email: emailId
            }
            browser.manage().addCookie("profile", profile, '/', applicationUrl)
            browser.manage().addCookie("id_token", authTokenId, '/', applicationUrl);
            defer.fulfill(body);
        }
    });
    return defer.promise;  
};
```